# Rails receive params as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, line-breaks

I'm building an API with Ruby on Rails. Because of that, I can't force the params to follow sone restriction.

Currently, I'm having an error with params that contained a Windows newline, because the newline isn't escaped.

The request body looks like below:

```
{
    "name": "Jon Do",
    "address": "6th Street\r\nDistrict City\r\nNation"
}
```

And it generated `JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token`

How to correctly process that request so `params[:address]` can be called without error?

Comment: how do u pass the data from front-end?

Comment: I built an external API, which means no front end for me

Answer (score 0):

When passing the data from front-end, make it `JSON.stringify`, and parse from back-end.

```
#Front-end
   address: JSON.stringify(objects)

#Back-end
   JSON.parse(params[:address])
```

Comment: I built an external API, which means no front end for me

Comment: its not matter, sent it as json. Also, if u can post yr sending request lines.